# on click event only working at first & second time in ReactJS-Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-hooks

I am here facing an interesting issue not sure why it is happening.
Basically i have set that for any on click event  will trigger the `toggleDropDown()` which will invert the condition `isDropdownOpen` (to true or false) and that will help in showing the dropdown menu `{isDropdownOpen ? <DropDownlist /> : false}`.

I am seeing after 1st click the condition for `isDropdownOpen` changes to true and thats fine and i click again it changest o false thats fine too but when i do the third click and any later click it remains false, and i can see the `elelel` remain on the nav bar, any suggestion where i am doing wrong. Thanks

- After `First` click on `usericon` in `navbar` ,`user-DropdownOpen`is set to true [image: After first click user-DropdownOpenis true]
- After `Second` and any later clicks,user-DropdownOpen`remains false [image]

1. **Updated code** below &small clip of current status [current behaviour of the application](https://youtu.be/NkTmoHXIzy0)

- `Snippet` of **Nav.js Component** code

```
   import history from "./History";

   function Nav({ userinfo, userstatus }) {
     const [isDropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
    const toggleDropDown = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
        history.push("/signin");
       return (
       <nav className="header">
         <label className="logo">
           <a href="/">
             <img className="yoga-image" src={ProjectLogo} />
           </a>
         </label>
   
         <ul>
           <li>
             <a
               className="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart
   "
               href="./basket"
             ></a>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a className="active" href="./signin">
               {userstatus ? (
                 <button
                   style={{ border: "none", background: "none", outline: "none" }}
                   className=" signin-icon glyphicon glyphicon-user    
                   "
                   onClick={(e) => toggleDropDown(e)}
                 ></button>
               ) : (
                 <button style={{ border: "none", background: "none", outline: "none" }} onClick={(e) => toggleDropDown(e)}>
                   SIGNIN
                 </button>
               )}
             </a>
           </li>
         </ul>
         {isDropdownOpen && <DropDownlist />}
       </nav>
     );
   }
```

- `Snippet` of **History.js Component** code

  ```
  import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";


  export default createBrowserHistory();
  ```
- `Snippet` of **App.js Component** code

  ````
    ```
     import Signin from "./Component/Signin";
     import history from "./History";
      return (
        <Router history={history}>

          <div className="App">
            <header className="header">
              <Nav userinfo={userData} userstatus={siginalready} />
            </header>..................
  ````

  ```
           <Switch>  // here we got switch statement contains(/,/basket,/signin) 
               <Route
              path="/"
              exact
              render={(props) => <Home {...props} userData={userData} userstatus={siginalready} addBasketitems={addBasketitems} />}
             />

            <Route
              path="/basket"
              exact
              render={(props) => (
                <Basket {...props} userData={userData} userstatus={siginalready} basketItems={basketItems} updatedBasket={updatedBasket} resetBasket={resetBasket} />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/signin"
              exact
              render={(props) => <Signin {...props} buyNow={buyNow} resetBuynow={resetBuynow} userData={userData} finalBuy={finalBuy} userstatus={siginalready} />}
            />
  ```

  ```
        <div className="footer">
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
  ```
- `Snippet` of **Signin.js Component** code

```
    function Signin({ userData, userstatus, finalBuy, buyNow, resetBuynow }) {
    
    
    //POST request to server...................and recieve Invoices
    
      return <div>{userstatus ? <Useraccount userinfo={userData} userstatus={userstatus} finalBuy={finalBuy} allInvoices={allInvoices} /> : <SigninOptions />}</div>;
    }
    export default Signin;
```

Comment: Why are you using the local storage to track if its open or not?

Comment: Initially i didnt use it but then, but then the `dropdown items` `elelel` is quick showing and then disappears, so i though use local storage to save the state permanent on each click

Answer (score 0):

Try setting initial state to false instead of getting it from the localStorage, so that its closed in the beginning (I suspect that this might be your issue, since when you set the state its already in the local storage and you will never get a false again as an initial condition, unless the storage is set to false):

```
  const [isDropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
```

Then when you are setting the state in the toggle function do:

```
setDropDownOpen(prevState => return { !prevState });
```

When you change a state of a component, you have to use the previous state to do that (might not be the actual issue that you are having, its just a good practice).

Then at the end of your function where you are rendering the DropDownList change it to:

```
{isDropDownOpen && <DropDownList />}
```

This is something like a "binary operator" so it will render DropDownList only if isDropDownOpen is true, otherwise it will not do anything.

I am suspecting that the issue might have to do something with the function that you made initialDropDownOpen(), see if the above changes fix it.

P.S. You can implement the changes one by one and see which if any of them fixes it :) and please let me know! :)

**EDIT:** Lift the state up, move

```
  const [isDropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
```

into the parent component and then add a property to your dropDown, for example call it `show`, so:

```
<Nav show={isDropDownOpen} toggle={setDropdownOpenWrapper} ...otherprops.../>
```

You have to wrap the set function and pass the wrapped function:

```
const setDropdownOpenWrapper = () => { setDropDown(prevState => return { !prevState}) };
```

and then use show and toggle inside the Nav component.

Comment: Thanks Darkbound for the above with explanation :), i have tried to implement the same but the issue still i am having is the text `elelel` is appearing and then disappers right away. just to mention withthat `Signin-user icon ` i am also fetching the data from the `DB` to update the other states and `pdf invoices` , so the only thing i thought was that it refreshes the state to default-false value and that was the reason i tried to use the localstorage, i have made a small clip to show  what i am facing `https://youtu.be/N0jITsGQsnQ` . any suggestions please

Comment: Okay, but now it is working, it is just closing right after that, right? If you console.log(isDropDownOpen) what happens? When you click it, it gets set to true, and then? Does it get set back to false on its own? Add a console.log right after the two states and let me know

Comment: I think that this is your problem, the parent component resets the state back to false, what you should do is "lift the state up", have the useState in the parent component and just pass down the value and the function. I am pretty sure that if you disable your fetch-es that when you click on the menu button elelelel probably will not even show or just blink, right now theres a slight delay, probably due to the fetching and when the fetching ends state is updated and child is rerendered with the false again

Comment: I updated my answer with suggestions for lifting the state up

Comment: I think you right with the state resetting to false, `liffting state up` i havent done it before, but i have replicated you code above, it is saying that setDropDownOpen not define , do i not have to pass the `isDropdownOpen & setDropdownOpen` both to the children in order for Nav component to recognise `setDropdownOpen`

Comment: Umair, I explained it in the answer, you need to wrap setDropDownOpen, you pass the setDropdownOpenWrapper function, re-read the last part :)

Comment: The wrapper function is basically the same as your toggle function ,you can still call it toggleDropdown instead of setDropdownOpenWrapper and pass it, just move it into the parent component, you have it already and pass it down

Comment: Thanks, let me have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening due to  tag have event attribute. When you click it, it tries to send form attached to it as default and redirect url or main domain. What you can do is simple. just using

```
e.preventDefault()
```

You need to update onClick and toggleDropDown functions like following

onClick;

```
            {userstatus ? (
              <button
                style={{ border: "none", background: "none", outline: "none" }}
                className=" signin-icon glyphicon glyphicon-user    "
                onClick={e => toggleDropDown(e)}
              ></button>
            ) : (
              <button
                style={{ border: "none", background: "none", outline: "none" }}
                onClick={e => toggleDropDown(e)}
              >
                SIGNIN
              </button>
            )}
```

toggleDropDown;

```
const toggleDropDown = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);
};
```

with these updates it will stay at your component or will not refresh the page or will not try to render your component again.

Also for localStorage you can use useEffect to update state.

define your state false/true as default, then write a useEffect hook.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("test")) {
      setDropdownOpen(localStorage.getItem("test"));
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. it does work but now i am facing another issue that , clicking on the icon is not taking me to `/signin` page anymore and neither it is fetching from the backend. is there a way i can tweak `e.preventDefault();` to only work except `toggleDropDown` .

Comment: i have  ```<Route
              path="/signin">``` in App.js too, so not sure if i can tweak something there.

Comment: if you want to render another component defined on router you can use this
`
import history from "[history variable location]"
const toggleDropDown = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);
  history.push('/signin')
};
`
history variable is where you defined your router

`<Router history={history}>`

Define history variable with export to access from other components
If you define history variable on other component than you can import it only with deconstruct import as
`import { history} from "[where history is]";`

Comment: I have made some changes in the code and updated the code (above), i have also made another small clip (above link) to show how the application looks like now. in short the `history.push` is not working if i add `history.go(0)` then it does bring the invoices from Backend but then `dropdown` flicks only. i am thinking rather rerender `/signin` shell i not rerender `<signin/> component, as that i think will avoid rerender Nav bar(which got the signinicon and dropdown).

Comment: but not sure if and how can i add `Signin component` to history.push. any suggestion please

Comment: Can you also share `/signin` route definition code, you have conditional rendering there most probably you need to figure out your props. Where is `userstatus` come and how you mutate it?

Comment: i have updated the code above with `/signin` its in the `Apps.js` component, i see i did use `render={(props) => <Signin {...props}...`in the route statement.... i am just learning bit by bit so actually i forgot why i used `{...props}`(and trying to understand why i need the props here) and if i delete the props so still i dont see any difference in the current output.

Comment: i have `  useEffect(() => {
    credentailverify();
  }, []);` in App.js so everytime it will do the API call to check the `usercredentail` and return the status and save in a `state/localstorage` and pass as to other components as `userstatus` , i have also updated the `Nav.js`  above.